# Javascript: link href target

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, onclick, dom-events

I'm using the standard Google Analytics Javascript code to track the outbound links on my website:

```
  function recordOutboundLink(link, category, action) {
    _gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent(category, action);
    setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100);
  }
```

Even when I add `"target='_blank'` to my links, all links are still opened in the same window/tab. I tried add `'document.location.target'`, but the script isn't working yet.

Comment: How is that function called? Meaning how is the click event bound to your links? did you `preventDefault()` the event (or at least `return false;`)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! My link are like: <a href="http://www.example.com" onClick="recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Links', 'example.com');return false;">

Comment: Why not simply `setTimeout(function(){ var newWin = window.open(this.href,'windowName'); }, 100);` rather than worrying about `target="_blank"` and so forth? With [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) a new window, or tab, will be opened automatically. Which at least *seems* easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.location = newURL` will open the URL in the existing window. You can use `window.open(newURL)` to open the URL in a new window.

A couple of other things:

1. `document.location` has been deprecated -- use `location.href` instead.
2. You can simplify your code by not passing in the action, and getting from the link href instead.

Try the following

```
<a href='http://example.com' onclick="return recordOutboundLink(this, 'Outbound Link');">

function recordOutboundLink(link, category) {
  var url = link.href;
  _gat._getTrackerByName()._trackEvent(category, url);
  if (link.target == '_blank') 
    window.open(url);
  else 
    setTimeout(function() {location.href = url;}, 150);
  return false;
}
```

FYI: Why use setTimeout only for opening the URL in the existing window? Starting to open a new URL in the existing window can halt the analytics tracking pixel request before it's completed. If you're opening the URL in a new window, there's no need for a delay.

Comment: Good answer but please reconsider passing a string to setTimeout as it is a form of eval
, you can pass:
function(){ location.href = location.href =url; }
instead